# Are the Intel S2600CP Server Board and SC5650 family Intel server chassis compatible?

Tags: compatibility, chassis

I am planning to try an Intel S2600CP Server Board and SC5650 family Intel server chassis together.

Are they compatible? Does anyone has an experience with this setup?

Answer (score 0):

One of the features of this chassis is that it validates with with Intel Server Boards.

I think it will work.

Comment: After checking i think this board only works with:
Intel® Server Chassis P4000M chassis

http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/s2600cp/sb/g26942005_s2600cp_p4000cp_tps_r1_8.pdf

Comment: thanks, Actually it does not work for some reason. As my CPU fan is quite big I decided to setup processor at CPU2 slot instead of CPU1 - does that make any difference ?

Comment: Not sure, can't help you with that one, sorry.

Comment: ok, it works now - there was a problem with fasteners which are too short - so when using all of them motherboard touches metal wall of the chassis preventing it from working. It does work when using a subset of fasteners